# Non-differentiability of a function of two variables at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have problems understanding this:

Function $\;g(x,y)\;$ is given, for which

a) $\;g_x(0,0)=7\;$

b) $\;g(t+2t^2,\sin3t+4t^2)=5e^t\;$

c) $\;\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(t,2t)-g(3t,4t)}t=10\;$

They ask to show there's a point for which $\;g\;$ isn't differentiable and what is that point.

I use b) to have that $g(t+2t^2,\sin3t+4t^2)=5e^t\to 5\;$ with $\;t\to 0\;$, and then it can't be continuous at origin since $\;g(0,0)=7\;$ and then not differentiable, but then I don't get what condition c) tells.

Comment: I have corrected a typing mistake in (a): it should be $\;g_x\;$, not only $\;g\;$ .

Comment: You don't know the value of $g(0,0)$. Condition (a) tells you the partial derivative with respect to $x$ exists in the origin and has value $7$.

Comment: You are right, @MarkFantini . I edited my question and, of course, the value of $\;g(0,0)\;$ is still unknown. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since two of three conditions have to do with $(0,0)$, the only reasonable conjecture for the point of non-differentiability is $(0,0)$.

So, suppose $g$ **is** differentiable at $(0,0)$, meaning there are constants $a,b$ such that 
$$
\frac{g(x,y)-g(0,0)-ax-by}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to 0 \quad \text{as } (x,y)\to (0,0) \tag{1}
$$

Plugging (a),(b),(c) into (1), you should be able to obtain that

- $a=7$
- $a+3b=5$
- $-2a -2b = 10$

Which is probably not consistent...

If you know the multivariable chain rule, use that instead of (1).

Comment: Dear @Care Bear, thank you very much for your answer. But I still cannot understand how you get that linear system with $\;a,b\;$ by "pluggin" conditions a,b,c in (1). The system certainly is not consistent (I already showed that), but I don't quite get the equations. For example, pluging $\;t=0\;$ in (b) I get $\;g(0,0)=5e^0=5\;$, and using (a) I get from (1) that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(g_x(x,y)-a)}x\;$ exists, so it must (?) be $\;g_x(0,0)=7=a\;$ in the above numerator...I'd appreciate a push in this directions.

Comment: For example, differentiability would imply that as $t\to 0$,   $g(t+2t^2,\sin3t+4t^2) = g(0,0)+a(t+2t^2)+b(\sin3t+4t^2) + o(t)$ where $o(t)$ means the term that goes to zero even after divided by $t$. The above can be rearranged to $g(t+2t^2,\sin3t+4t^2) = g(0,0)+at+3bt + o(t)$ by putting more of the stuff into $o(t)$. On the other hand, $5e^{ t}=5+5t+o(t)$. Hence $2+3b=5$.

Comment: Dear @Care Bear : in your last line of your last comment, you meant $\;a+3b=5\;$, did not you? Thanks for any further help.